# why forEach method returns type of array elements indices as number instead of string?

Tags: javascript

I know the array index type is `string` but when I use `forEach()` the result is `number`, so I wonder why this is happening?

code:

```
const a1 = ["lome", "kevin", 56];


a1.forEach((val, index) => console.log(typeof index))

//result: number
```

```
 const a1 = ["lome", "kevin", 56];


 for(i in a1){
 console.log(typeof i);
 };
 
 //result: string
```

Comment: Why are you expecting the type of index to be anything but a number?

Comment: because they are strings? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: This behaviour is what is in the documentation? Is your question why the language was designed this way? That will be a matter of opinion...

Comment: this is because `object.forEach` has no idea about "arrays" or "indexes". It simply iterates numbers `for n from 0 to object.length` and looks whether a property `String(n)` exists in `object`.

Comment: @trincot: your duplicates are about `for..in` specifically, none of them covers `for..in` vs `forEach`, which is the OP question.

Comment: "*I know the array index type is `string`*" - only if you make the mistake of enumerating the object's own properties (`Object.keys`, `for (const key in arr)`). But this is generally not what you want. `for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++)`, `forEach`, `.entries()` etc do not use keys, they **count** until the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `forEach()`, the return is an index, that's why its type is `number`. The `for` loop iterates the object and considers the properties as strings, that's why their type is `string`.

> Receives a string property name on each iteration. May be either a declaration with const, let, or var, or an assignment target (e.g. a previously declared variable, an object property, or a destructuring assignment pattern). Variables declared with var are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same scope the for...in loop is in.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#variable